# convert utc timestamp to est in unix awk

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

I am searching for a range of files in unix but the problem is my input data is in UTC format I have to convert firs to EST and then apply filter is there a way in unix awk ?

```
awk '$2FS >="2017-02-21T11:09:41.000Z" && $2FS <="2017-02-23T11:09:41.000Z"'
```

Is there anything simple enough some thing like the below:

```
awk 'convert_to_date($2FS,'EST') >="2017-02-21T11:09:41.000Z"
&& convert_to_date($2FS,'EST') <="2017-02-23T11:09:41.000Z"'
```

Comment: POSIX awk or gawk? gawk is standard on lines and has time functions.

Comment: anything (awk,gawk or perl) which solves above problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try below bash solution -

cat time.txt

```
1 2017-02-22T11:09:41.000Z
2 2017-02-23T11:09:41.000Z
3 2017-02-24T11:09:41.000Z
4 2017-02-25T11:09:41.000Z
5 2017-02-26T11:09:41.000Z



    cat ./time.sh
#!/bin/bash
d="2017-02-21T11:09:41.000Z"
b="2017-02-23T11:09:41.000Z"
USERTIME1=`awk -F'[T]|[-]|[:]|[.]' '{datetime=mktime($1 " "$2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5 " " $6); print datetime}' <<< $d`
USERTIME2=`awk -F'[T]|[-]|[:]|[.]' '{datetime=mktime($1 " "$2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5 " " $6); print datetime}' <<< $b`
for i in `cat time.txt|awk '{print $2}'`
do
var=`awk 'BEGIN{FS="[T]|[-]|[:]|[.]"} {print mktime($1 " "$2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5 " " $6)}' <<< $i`
var1=`expr $var - 21600`
if [ $var1 -ge $USERTIME1 ] && [ $var1 -le $USERTIME2 ]
then
echo "$i"
fi
done
```

output of script :

```
./time.sh
2017-02-22T11:09:41.000Z
2017-02-23T11:09:41.000Z
```

I was trying to solve this using awk only but didn't succeed, if anyone can help. Here is the code -

```
### 1:11 AM Friday, Eastern Time (ET) is
### 6:11 AM Friday, Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)
### UTC to EST is 6 hour of difference means (-21600)
BEGIN{FS="[T]|[-]|[:]|[.]";d="2017-02-25T11:09:41.000Z";b="2017-02-23T11:09:41.000Z"}
{
USERTIME1=(substr(d,0,4) " " substr(d,6,2) " "substr(d,9,2) " " substr(d,12,2) " " substr(d,15,2) " "substr(d,18,2) " " substr(d,21,2))
USERTIME2=(substr(b,0,4) " " substr(b,6,2) " "substr(b,9,2) " " substr(b,12,2) " " substr(b,15,2) " "substr(b,18,2) " " substr(b,21,2))
UTCTIME=($1 " "$2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5 " " $6)
ESTTIME=(UTCTIME-21600)
if((mktime(ESTTIME) >= mktime(USERTIME1)) && mktime((ESTTIME) <= mktime(USERTIME2))
print
}
```

Comment: can we apply awk -F to a pipe stream ,can we apply to below pipe stream example I tried it but wasnt able to figure it out, example   aws s3api list-objects  --bucket bucket --prefix folder --query 'Contents[*][Key,LastModified]' --output text | grep -i filesearch | awk '$2FS >="2017-02-21T11:09:41.000Z" && $2FS <="2017-02-23T11:09:41.000Z"' | awk '{ gsub("T"," ",$2); gsub("Z","",$2);gsub("-","",$2);gsub(":","",$2);gsub(".000","",$2);print }' | awk '{a=$1;b=$2""$3;d=b-21600;c=b;print a,c,d}'